# History report on custom currency field

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I need to make a history report on my standar Opportunity object, which has a custom currency field (i need to be a different one than 'amount').

I already set the history tracking to that field, but when i create a history report on Opportunities i don't see it in the opptys historical field list.

How can i make that report? i also tried with historical field report, but that one doesnt allows me to summarize the field (and i need that to display it on the Y axis).

I tried with historical trending report too, but that one just allows me to show the historical changes over 5 days max, i need a full historical report.

Have i some alternative to all this?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: 1) Field history tracking on custom currency fields will work fine but will only track changes on a go forward basis; (2) Reporting on any object's field histories is very limited; (3) Opportunity Historical Trending should go back 90 days - however, the 90 day look back is only as good as whether you were tracking the custom field that long